# Accessing hierarchical nodes in firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Helo, I want to get the coupon details of each coupons from the `Coupon` node (As shown in the picture below) present in a hierarchy in firebase database.
[image]

I want to retrieve all the coupons from the `Coupon` node and show in a listview..
I am trying this code to fetch the database reference , but every time it gets to null reference ..

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("VendorDtl").child("vendor1").child("Coupons");
```

And I also tried..

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference().child("VendorDtl").child("vendor1").child("Coupons");
```

But eachtime I fail to get the right refernce to the database..
As a result the listview shows up but with null values..

And here is the code deployed to fetch the values..

```
   protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //attaching value event listener
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //clearing the previous artist list
            cpnlist.clear();

            //iterating through all the nodes
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.i("valueeventDb","tHIS IS CALLED");
                //getting artist
                CouponDetails coups= ds.getValue(CouponDetails.class);
                //adding artist to the list
                cpnlist.add(coups);           
            }

            //creating adapter
            CouponAdp cpnAdp = new CouponAdp(ShowCoupons.this, cpnlist);
            //attaching adapter to the listview
            couplist.setAdapter(cpnAdp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"EROrrr Fetching value ... ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the adapter code..

```
public class CouponAdp extends ArrayAdapter<CouponDetails> {
private Activity context;
List<CouponDetails> shpsv;

public CouponAdp(Activity context, List<CouponDetails> objects) {
    super(context,R.layout.item_list,objects);
    this.context=context;
    this.shpsv=objects;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {


    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
    }

    TextView coupNm = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    TextView coupDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView15);
    TextView coupSts = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView17);
    TextView coupValidity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView19);
    TextView coupValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView21);
    TextView coupCatg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView23);

   CouponDetails shp=shpsv.get(position);

    coupNm.setText(shp.getScnm());
    coupDesc.setText(shp.getScdesc());
    coupSts.setText(shp.getScsts());
    coupValidity.setText(shp.getScval_from()+" to "+shp.getScval_to());
    coupValue.setText(shp.getSc_percentage());
    coupCatg.setText(shp.getSc_catg());

    return convertView;

}
```

How can I fetch the coupons-details correctly and show details on listview ?

Though my app dosen't show any errror directly!!
The logcat shows...

```
    01-19 21:02:58.502 27083-28252/com.example.vendorapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
01-19 21:02:58.547 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{522cae9 V.ED..... ......ID 103,94-256,143 #7f08002a app:id/bb_bottom_bar_title} during layout: running second layout pass
01-19 21:02:58.547 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{2d9936e V.ED..... ......ID 40,94-319,143 #7f08002a app:id/bb_bottom_bar_title} during layout: running second layout pass
01-19 21:02:58.547 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{6a37a0f V.ED..... ......ID 107,94-251,143 #7f08002a app:id/bb_bottom_bar_title} during layout: running second layout pass
01-19 21:02:58.551 27083-27092/com.example.vendorapp I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=121KB, data=108KB
01-19 21:02:58.552 27083-27092/com.example.vendorapp I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=121KB, data=108KB
01-19 21:02:58.552 27083-27092/com.example.vendorapp I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
01-19 21:02:58.553 27083-27092/com.example.vendorapp I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 8MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
01-19 21:02:58.567 27083-28252/com.example.vendorapp D/FA: Connected to remote service
01-19 21:02:58.567 27083-28252/com.example.vendorapp V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
01-19 21:03:03.050 27083-28252/com.example.vendorapp V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 4583
01-19 21:03:03.051 27083-28252/com.example.vendorapp V/FA: Activity paused, time: 264940263
01-19 21:03:03.056 27083-28252/com.example.vendorapp D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=4583, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Promotion, firebase_screen_id(_si)=7031206903639617093}]
01-19 21:03:03.076 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp V/FA: onActivityCreated
01-19 21:03:03.145 27083-27092/com.example.vendorapp I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
01-19 21:03:03.165 27083-28252/com.example.vendorapp V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 264940378
01-19 21:03:03.169 27083-28252/com.example.vendorapp D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=Promotion, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=7031206903639617093, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Coupons, firebase_screen_id(_si)=7031206903639617094}]
01-19 21:03:03.242 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{b514d73 V.ED..... ......ID 103,94-256,143 #7f08002a app:id/bb_bottom_bar_title} during layout: running second layout pass
01-19 21:03:03.242 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{1293430 V.ED..... ......ID 40,94-319,143 #7f08002a app:id/bb_bottom_bar_title} during layout: running second layout pass
01-19 21:03:03.243 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{99208a9 V.ED..... ......ID 107,94-251,143 #7f08002a app:id/bb_bottom_bar_title} during layout: running second layout pass
01-19 21:03:03.258 27083-27092/com.example.vendorapp I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=249KB, data=183KB
01-19 21:03:03.259 27083-27092/com.example.vendorapp I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=240KB, data=145KB
01-19 21:03:03.334 27083-27220/com.example.vendorapp D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x78bc848400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x78bdfc88a0
01-19 21:03:04.158 27083-28252/com.example.vendorapp V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 994
01-19 21:03:04.159 27083-28252/com.example.vendorapp V/FA: Activity paused, time: 264941372
01-19 21:03:04.185 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp V/FA: onActivityCreated
01-19 21:03:04.211 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: IPerf::tryGetService failed!
01-19 21:03:04.306 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
01-19 21:03:04.306 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
01-19 21:03:04.344 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
01-19 21:03:04.387 27083-28252/com.example.vendorapp V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 264941600
01-19 21:03:04.392 27083-28252/com.example.vendorapp D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=Coupons, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=7031206903639617094, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ShowCoupons, firebase_screen_id(_si)=7031206903639617095}]
01-19 21:03:04.411 27083-28380/com.example.vendorapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
01-19 21:03:04.543 27083-27220/com.example.vendorapp D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x78ba5afc00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x78d611cb40
01-19 21:03:05.840 27083-27092/com.example.vendorapp I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=249KB, data=169KB
01-19 21:03:05.841 27083-27092/com.example.vendorapp I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=249KB, data=169KB
01-19 21:03:05.841 27083-27092/com.example.vendorapp I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
01-19 21:03:06.508 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp I/valueeventDb: tHIS IS CALLED
01-19 21:03:06.522 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponCategory found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.523 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponStatus found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.523 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponName found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.523 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponValue found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.523 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponDesc found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.523 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponvalidFrom found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.523 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponvalidTo found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.532 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp I/valueeventDb: tHIS IS CALLED
01-19 21:03:06.532 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponCategory found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.533 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponStatus found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.533 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponName found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.533 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponValue found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.533 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponDesc found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.533 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponvalidFrom found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.533 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponvalidTo found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.541 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp I/valueeventDb: tHIS IS CALLED
01-19 21:03:06.542 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponCategory found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.542 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponStatus found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.542 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponName found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.542 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponValue found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.542 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponDesc found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.542 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponvalidFrom found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:06.542 27083-27083/com.example.vendorapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for CouponvalidTo found on class com.example.vendorapp.CouponDetails
01-19 21:03:09.477 27083-28252/com.example.vendorapp V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference couponsRef = rootRef.child("VendorDtl").child("vendor1").child("Coupons");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<CouponDetails> cpnlist = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            CouponDetails coups = ds.getValue(CouponDetails.class);
            cpnlist.add(coups);
            Log.d("TAG", coups.getCouponName());
        }
        couplist.setAdapter(cpnAdp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
couponsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

As you can see, I have declared and used `cpnlist` inside `onDataChange()` method, otherwise is always `null`, due its asynchronous behaviour.

**Edit:**

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference couponsRef = rootRef.child("VendorDtl").child("vendor1").child("Coupons");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<CouponDetails> cpnlist = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String couponCategory = ds.child("CouponCategory").getValue(String.class);
            String couponDesc = ds.child("CouponDesc").getValue(String.class);
            String couponName= ds.child("CouponName").getValue(String.class);
            String couponStatus = ds.child("CouponStatus").getValue(String.class);
            String couponValue = ds.child("CouponValue").getValue(String.class);
            String couponValidFrom = ds.child("CouponvalidFrom").getValue(String.class);
            String couponValidTo = ds.child("CouponValidTo").getValue(String.class);

            CouponDetails shp = new CouponDetails(couponCategory, couponDesc, couponName, couponStatus, couponValue, couponValidFrom, couponValidTo);
            cpnlist.add(shp);
            Log.d("TAG", couponName);
        }
        couplist.setAdapter(cpnAdp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
couponsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: -Though my app directly dosen't show any error..I am giving the logcat @Alex Mamo

Comment: Do you all the coupons name in the logcat? In the for loop is a `Log.d("TAG", coups.getCouponName())` Does this line of code print anything?

Comment: I have removed that errirenous line in my acttual code

Comment: Put it back and say to me out out logs the names of the coupons in the logcat

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message` is in logcat while i put that method back   ..@Alex Mamo

Comment: So you are getting or not the name of the coupons in the logcat?

Comment: no its showing that error on that particular line `Log.d`    And earlier i had got null value

Comment: See my updated answer. Is now printing in the logcat the name of the coupon?

Comment: I had solved that earlier..so I didn't need to test ur answer..thank u for ur support..but which is for single event..I have to fetch multiple times...not for single event..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for fetching the coupons :

```
public class ActivityClassName extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<CouponDetails> couponDetailsArrayList;
    FirebseDatabase database;
    ListView couponListView;
    CouponAdp couponAdp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout_id);

        couponDetailsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        couponListView = findViewbyId(R.id.your_list_view_id);
        couponAdp = new CouponAdp(ActivityClassName.this,couponDetailsArrayList);

        getCoupons();

    }

    private void getCoupons(){
        couponDetailsArrayList.clear();
        DatabaseReference vendorGroup = database.getReference("VendorDtl");
        vendorGroup.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // for each vendor get inside the block(node)
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    // inside each vendor get all the coupons
                    for(DataSnapshot coupon : snapshot.child("Coupons").getChildren());
                        couponDetailsArrayList.add(coupon.getValue(CouponDetails.class));
                couponAdp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                couponListView.setAdapter(couponAdp);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i("CouponFetchError: ",databaseError.getMessage();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here **addValueEventListener()** function will constantly monitor the online database and change contents of **couponListView** in realtime. It is a good practice to remove the listener but Firebase client will automatically handle it after activity gets destroyed.

If you want to avoid constant monitoring and want to monitor just for once and fetch data and repeat fetching data whenever you want, then replace

```
vendorGroup.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

with

```
vendorGroup.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

[Refer here for more details](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-reading-once)

and fetch details whenever you want by calling function:

```
getCoupons();
```

Hope this works !!